# Position image correctly on card

Tags: html, css

I have to implement the image on the right side but even on setting float to the right it's positioning doesn't change....

```
<mat-card>
      <mat-card-title class="report-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Mul2">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <p class="image1" [innerHTML]="jsonDataTempX.image"></p>
        </div>
        <p class="report-titles" style="margin-top: -3%;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Mul2">
          {{jsonDataTempX.description}} <i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="color: black"></i>
          <span class="percentage-align12" >
          {{jsonDataTempX.range_percentage | number:0}}%</span>
        </p>
      </mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content id="Mul2" class="collapse">
        <p class="collapse-message"  [innerHTML]="jsonDataTempX.summary_message"></p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

CSS

```
.image1{
  float: right;
  margin: 0 100%;
}

.report-titles{
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:400;
  line-height: 1.3;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  color: #000000;
}
```

This is what I got

[image]

Need to look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just add img tag in front of image tag :

```
.image1 img{
  float: right;
  margin: 0 100%;
}
```